# IIS URL Rewrite - Change Beginning of URL

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I would like to replace

```
https://web1.domain.org/cwweb/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://web1.domain.org/
```

with

```
https://web2.domain.org/cwweb/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://web2.domain.org/
```

and keep everything else after it.

e.g. "https://web2.domain.org/xxxxx/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://web2.domain.org/xxxxx&thisid=zzzz"

This is what I have tried:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect app" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="web1.domain.org" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://web2.domain.org/cwweb/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://web2.domain.org/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This is what it displays: ""https://web2.domain.org/xxxxx/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://web1.domain.org/xxxxx&thisid=zzzz"

The second domain name doesn't change.

I pretty much a noob with this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^cwweb/LauncherInterface.aspx$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="web1.domain.org" />
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)web1(\.domain\.org.*)" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://web2.domain.org/{R:0}?{C:1}web2{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The first domain name changed but the second did not "https://web2.domain.org/cwweb/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://web1.domain.org"     Test pattern test confirmed C:1 is "https://web1.domain.org/cwweb/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://" and C:2 is ".domain.org" Any other ideas?

Comment: What data did you test with? I posted a screenshot of my test in the answer. may be you can refer to this link about query string. [https://propellent.io/web-engineering/remove-query-string-parameter-with-url-rewrite/](https://propellent.io/web-engineering/remove-query-string-parameter-with-url-rewrite/).

Comment: I referenced your test and it looks correct. I'm off for several days and will update with any new info.

Comment: Is your problem solved?